# adding a wait page when first loading asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What's the best way to add a loading page/splash page when a user first comes to my asp.net mvc application.

Is there a way to add it so I want have to change the way it is accessed?

What are some different ways to do this?

Thanks,

rod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery to show a layer with absolute position and a high z-index (layer overlay) that hides all your application (for instance to show advertising) or simulate a loading page (but this is not a strict loading page).

I think you should avoid the use of this methods cause is annoying for the users.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show it only once, when Session_Start (Global.asax event) runs, put something like this on Session

```
Session["showLoading"] = true;
```

Then on your view just check if it's true and show a layer like Josemalive said. After that, remove that key from Session.

Hope it helps.